# Заполнение одномерного массива случайными числами

Tags: c

Ниже представлен кусок кода, который, так сказать, генерирует мат. модель для пакета LP-solve, где принимают участие 853 узла АТС, и здесь отражена попытка написать балансовые уравнения и пропускные способности узлов.Он генерирует 50 ограничений (как мне надо) по количеству строк. Единственная проблема - убрать повторяющиеся случайно генерируемые числа в строке для j и в столбце для i, то есть чтобы не выводил подобные результаты:

`x81 = x180 + x196 + x103 + x196;`

или

`x34 = x112 + x130 + x116;`

или

`x34 = x123 + x135 + x184;`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fl;
int n, j, i, k;
fl = fopen("myone.lp", "w");
n = 8;

fprintf(fl, "max: x0 ;\n\n");
fprintf(fl, "x0 = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5;\n\n");
for (j=1; j<=100; j++)
{
    fprintf(fl, "x%d <= %d;\n", j, rand() % 4 +1);
}
for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
{
    i = (k - 1) * 100;
    j = k * 100;
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1);
    fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1, j+rand() % 99 +1);
    for (j=1; j<=100; j++)
    {
        fprintf(fl, "x%d <= %d;\n", 100*k+j, rand() % 4 +1);
    }
}
for (j=1; j<=53; j++)
{
    fprintf(fl, "x%d <= %d;\n", 800+j, rand() % 4 +1);
}
fclose(fl);
printf("\nThat is all!");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: А можно теперь безо всякой воды, чуть более внятно и почётче, объяснить что конкретно нужно? Если надо отслеживать чтобы каждое новое случайное число было уникальным, то, в соответствии с тегом, можно воспользоваться, например, `std::map<int,bool>` для хранения уже полученных чисел.

Comment: да просто `std::set<int>` завести и забивать его до тех пор, пока не будет там необходимого количества. Повторений он сам не допустит.

Comment: ну и `rand()`, конечно, не лучшее средство для генерация псевдослучайных чисел.

Comment: честно говоря, я  программировании новичок, поэтому из того, что вы написали, я ничего не понял. выручите и напишите как это конкретно вот реализуется. Я был бы вам очень благодарен. Задача проста, что бы в строке не было повторяющихся чисел для j и не было одинаковых чисел в столбце для i. Увы, как реализовать - не знаю

Comment: @АнтонНикитин, в первую очередь нужно определиться: C или C++. Это совершенно разные языки, разные библиотеки, разные подходы etc. В теге написано C++, а код - чисто сишный. Надо выбрать что-то одно.

Comment: спасибо, @klopp, исправил.

Comment: и все-таки как здесь реализовать этот момент? я новичок. поэтому не судите строго. то, что предложил outcast - не совсем понял :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку Вам требуется получить (исходя из `rand() % 99`) действительно небольшое (десятки, м.б. сотни штук) множество случайных чисел, то можно предложить весьма простой способ их генерации, а точнее проверки на уникальность, работающий как в Си, так и в C++.

Его суть заключается в использовании вспомогательного массива (по сути это будет представление множества), элементы которого индексируются нашими случайными числами. Сначала проинициализируем массив нулями, а по мере выработки чисел будем устанавливать его соответствующие элементы, что означает -- такое число уже было.

Впрочем, наверное код лучше всего прояснит выше сказанное:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 99

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int rnum[N];        // результат -- N разных чисел
  char used[N] = {0}; // вспомогательный массив
                      // его можно уменьшить в 8 раз
                      // перейдя к работе с битами
                      // но здесь, для простоты, я это делать не буду
                      // (учитывая комментарии автора о том, что он ...)

  srand(time(0));     // так будем делать разные последовательности 
  int i = 0;
  while (i < N) {
    rnum[i] = rand() % N;  // пробуем очередное число
    if (!used[rnum[i]]) {  // такого еще не было
      used[rnum[i]] = 1;
      i++;                 // перейдем к генерации следующего числа
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)  // OK. Сгенерили все N разных чисел.
    printf("%d\n", rnum[i]);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Если вопросы остались, задавайте.

Comment: и теперь плюсуем rnum[i] к i? чтобы в строке элементы не повторялись?

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень хорошо представляю, что именно и где у Вас не может повторяться. Формально, если к каждому числу в `rnum[]` прибавить одно и то же число, то получившиеся числа тоже все будут разными.

Comment: fprintf(fl, "x%d = x%d + x%d + x%d;\n", i + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1, j + rand() % 99 +1); в этой строке элемент, которые генерируются с помощью rand() % 99 +1 могут повторяться. вот это надо исключить

Comment: Да не надо вам ничего "генерировать в строке". Вы сначала создаёте массив, который заполнен неповторяющимися случайными числами (в данном примере - `rnum[N]`). А потом используете его в своих подстановках. В качестве первого `%d` берёте `rnum[0]` (вместо `j + rand() % 99 +1`) , в качестве второго - `rnum[1]` и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Так получить уникальные числа во множество uniq_rnd:

```
set<int> uniq_rnd;
srand( **начальное_число_для_генератора** )
for( int i = 0; i < **сколько_надо_чисел**; ++i )
 uniq_rnd.insert( rand() );

while( uniq_rnd.size() < **сколько_надо_чисел** )
 uniq_rnd.insert( rand() );
```

Так их использовать:

```
set<int>::const_iterator r = uniq_rnd.begin(), e = uniq_rnd.end()
for( ; r != e; ++r )
{
 int cur_rnd = *r;
 ....здесь что-то делаем с числом cur_rnd....
}
```

P.S. Код не оптимальный, но более-менее рабочий

P.P.S. Не пиши никогда так `for (j=1; j<=53; j++)` циклы, называй границы как-то осмысленно, а не просто 53. Применяй циклы по назначению там где повторяются одинаковые строки, не надо бездумно копипастить - единственное применение такому коду как у тебя - на мусорке.

Comment: "код не оптимальный" да уж, особенно осмысленным выглядит первый цикл... "не пиши никогда так!" :-)

Comment: это я прекрасно понимаю, но раз работает - и слава богу.

Comment: ну, что поделать?) не прогер :) тогда как лучше?

Comment: если видишь что фрагмент кода повторяется много раз почти без изменений - вынеси его в отдельную функцию, а вызов функции помести внутрь цикла чтобы обеспечить нужное количество повторов